# Alternately reverse div class values in smarty foreach loop

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, smarty

I'm trying to make a fancy banner module on my webstite to show alternately banners like this:
[image]

But the result is like this...
[image]

The code looks like this

```
{foreach blablabla}
    <div class="{cycle values="col-md-7,col-md-5"} col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pzero">
         <a href="{$slide.url|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" title="{$slide.description|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">
             <img src="#" alt="{$slide.legend|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" class="img-responsive" />
         </a>
    </div>
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you're doing a cycle with a set of 2 values, but what you really need are 4 (black,gray,gray,black)

So just repeat them:

```
{cycle values="col-md-7,col-md-5,col-md-5,col-md-7"}
```